# if else in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to iterate through an array of objects (contacts) with multiple properties and check for two conditions.
If both conditions are true, I want the value of (prop) to be returned , if any of them fails, "No such contact" should be returned.

The code works with the if statement only, but as soon as I add the else, it returns "No such contact" even if both conditions are true. 
Where do I place the else to allow the loop iterate over all objects before the else kicks in?

```
checkName(name, prop){
for (i = 0; i <= contacts.length-1; i++) {
    if (name === contacts[i].firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return(contacts[i][prop]);
    } else {
        return("No such contact");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: typo in your if statement? try fixing `&` for `&&` also you can use a `forEach` to more easily loop through your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a single `&`, you need to be using two like this: `&&`

However, since you're using `return`, you're exiting the function on the first execution. You'll want to move the return to outside of the loop so that after the for loop, if it hasn't exited, it'll return that none were found.

```js
checkName(name, prop){
    for (i = 0; i <= contacts.length-1; i++) {
        if (name === contacts[i].firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return(contacts[i][prop]);
        }
    }
    return("No such contact");
}
```

Comment: Same happens with &&. The problem is not with the if statement, when I execute it without the else, it works fine, as soon as I add the else, it returns the else value even when the condition is true. Makes me think that it iterates through the array, the condition for the first element is false, so it returns the else and stops iterating.

Comment: @Gigi read the second paragraph...

Comment: In this case the only difference between `&` and `&&` is that the latter [short-circuits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @Ivar Not exactly, as `&` is bitwise-and. `2 && true` returns a truthy value (`true`), `2 & true` returns a falsy value (`0`)

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that the return exits the function, thanks.

Comment: @Samathingamajig Both sides of the operator return boolean values, so in this case, they always return the same.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the wrong using AND operator ([bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) vs [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND)), you need to declare the variable `i` and just loop until `i` is smaller than then length.

But the main problem is to exit early if the first check is not true and the function returns with message.

To avoid this, you need to move the message to the end of the function after all items have been visited.

Another hint, actually only a cosmetic part, remove irritating braces of the return expression.

```
function checkName(name, prop) {
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (name === contacts[i].firstName && & contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
}
```

Comment: `&& &` ? Did you mean `&&`

Comment: Thanks Nina. It worked! Thanks for the suggestion on cosmetics too.